# How can i get the url from an Image using two activities?

Tags: android

I have two activities, one called listview, and a second activity called informations, it shows specific information about a specific user.

And i would like to pass one image from the listview, to the informations activity.

To get the image URL from the User, I'm trying to use a Intent.

**Listview activity**

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        String checkid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id))
                .getText().toString();


        String checkimage = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image)).getContext().toString();


        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
               UserProfile.class);

        in.putExtra("teste", checkid);
        in.putExtra("teste2", checkimage);

        startActivity(in);


    }
});
```

**Informations activity**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

String id = intent.getStringExtra("teste");
String image = intent.getStringExtra("teste2");

Picasso.with(this)
.load(image)
.into(imageView);
```

But is not working, how can i do that?

Comment: what exactly doesn't work, be more specific

Comment: I can't get the URL from the ImageView.

Comment: I would like to pass an image from an activity to another. And to do that, i need to get the URL from the image again, i used picasso to put the image inside the ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the way to get the URL from your image. This is wrong.

```
String checkimage = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image)).getContext().toString();
```

You can set a Tag to your ImageView however, but you need to to this in your Adapter. `imageView.setTag(url)` and then retrive it like `String url = (String)((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image)).getTag();`

Comment: I know that I am doing it wrong, thats why I need help, i need to know the right way to do that.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Please close this thread by accepting this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap implements `Parcelable`, so you could always pass it in the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

and retrieve it on the other end:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

that's how you can pass an iage from an activity to another.